# WCF Service with Output Cache Profile sets Vary: * header

Tags: wcf, outputcache, vary

I have a WCF service which uses an OutputCacheProfile to get a one hour output cache time

```
<add name="GetVisitorSettingsCache" location="Any" duration="3600" enabled="true" varyByParam="groupid;service;site;ver" />
```

The output caching works, but responses include header `Vary: *`, which prevents the browser from using a cached the response.
I believe I am running into the bug described here:
https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/introduction-to-an-outputcache-bug-that-accompanied-asp-net-from-10-to-40_1_36_32422553.html
The workaround is to call `Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);`
except in my case I have a WCF service and do not know how to use the workaround in that context

Is there any way to call SetOmitVaryStar() for a WCF service?
Is there some other workaround?

I tried programmatically setting the vary header:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("vary", "");
```

but it had no effect

Setting location="ServerAndClient" in the OutputCacheProfile did not help either.

I am thinking of using a Web API controller instead and using this:
https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.CacheOutput but that is a last resort.

**Update**

I tried the suggestion from Ding Peng below, with code in `BeforeSendReply` attempting to remove the vary header:

```
webOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove("vary");
```

However the vary * header still appears in the response, as if the output cache mechanism is adding it back after this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDispatchMessageInspector interface, here is my demo:

```
public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

        WebOperationContext webOperationContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
        webOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("vary", "*");
    }
}
```

We can add response headers in IDispatchMessageInspector.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

We also need to add ServerMessageLogger to the behavior of the service.

Finally we need to apply CustContractBehavior to the service:

[image]

The following figure is the response header obtained by the browser:

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: I am trying this out.  I am actually trying to *remove* the vary header.  In "BeforeSendReply" I have:             webOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("testheader", "hello");
            webOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove("vary");
I can see that the response has the testheader : hello.  But it still includes vary : *.  The debugger shows that the vary header is getting removed, but something must be adding it back after that point?

Comment: No need to add other header.

Comment: The other header was just to prove that the code was having an effect.  The question remains how to I remove the vary : * header from the response?

Comment: In order to determine whether the output caching mechanism will add "vary" after the BeforeSendReply method, I think you can check whether there is "vary" in the BeforeSendReply method.

Comment: What is interesting is that the vary: * header is already present by BeforeSendReply, and the code to remove it (see my updated answer above) appears to work when I inspect the headers in the debugger.  But the response still includes Vary: *